# How to filter and get particular value from Rest call response

Tags: rest, postman

I am trying to fetch child deployment ID which is present inside my labels (parent deployment result. Attached below). Somehow I am not able to get it's values (especially 2nd dictionary value I want).

[image]

Could you please how to do this in GET request query. Without any external script to parse this output.

```
https://<url>/api/v3.1/deployments/<dep-id>?&_include=labels
```

With this query I am able to get till label output like below

```
{
    "labels": [
        {
            "key": "csys-consumer-id",
            "value": "vm15-getlmcname-0",
            "created_at": "2023-08-08T13:36:17.646Z",
            "creator_id": 35
        },
        {
            "key": "csys-consumer-id",
            "value": "vm15-nmcwork-el14665-0",
            "created_at": "2023-08-08T13:36:32.643Z",
            "creator_id": 35
        }
]
}
```

But I want to get only this **vm15-nmcwork-el14665-0**

What I need to change in this http request:

```
 https://<url>/api/v3.1/deployments/<dep-id>?&_include=labels
```

to get that value? Please help me.

Comment: Well hard to say without knowledge of API. Please share more about the API, is this API custom implemented or using it from other vendors?

Comment: This is output of cloudify deployment result and consider custom implemented (Attached screenshot). Always for any deployment these values will be updated but keys will be same. I am able to get upto  lables (list of dict) but I need 3rd dict value this time. Kindly help me how to get that

Comment: _but I need 3rd dict value this time._ Where you want to get it? into Postman test script? if NOT then this not related to Postman

Comment: Sorry, My question is very simple is there any way to get that particular value through api response.

Comment: You can definitely get it from the api response, use Postman test script to parse the response and pick only what you want. Doing it using an URL (directly ) is not possible I believe! _only possible if cloudify provides that filtering using an URL_